# Ho to enable If-Modified-Since HTTP header in my web site

Tags: php, caching

I want to implement If-Modified-Since HTTP header in my site. How do I ensure the If-Modified-Since HTTP header is supported and that it is active?. If it is supported but not active then how to make it active?

Do I have to make any necessary configuration in htaccess  or in apache server's.conf file to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

This header is related to your HTTP server configuration.
If you are using Apache, see **Expires** module. You'll have to set some cache configuration for your assets, example

```
# Turn on cache control
ExpiresActive On
# Enable caching for PNG image (1 week)
ExpiresByType image/png M604800
```

If you are using another HTTP server, read the doc.

Comment: I have following configuration in .conf file but it still not workin
I dont know where I am going wrong 

  FileETag MTime Size
  ExpiresActive On                                                                                                                                                         
  <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
   ExpiresDefault A604800
  </FilesMatch>